# How to get array out of object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I was trying to get data from the notes array in the data object. I'm getting the object from mongodb and I want to get the array called notes. but I can't do it. for some reason. In java there is like  Object.get(notes) and I can get a specific field within the object but I don't know how to do that in js. And I haven't been able to find something that works elsewhere online.

here is my code

```
axios.post('/api/user/notes')
.then(res => {
   console.log( Object.values(res.data));
   dataSet = Object.values(res.data); 
   console.log(dataSet[0]); 
   console.log(dataSet.notes[0]);      
   
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('it didnt work' + err); 
});
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gdVU.png)

Comment: Try with `res.data.map(({ notes }) => notes)`

Comment: res.data is an array....object in that array has notes property ... try `res.data[0].notes` No need for Object.values()

Answer (score 1):

`dataSet` is an array. So, to get the notes, you have to first select the first element of data, `dataSet[0]` and then the notes array. To get the first note, it would be `dataSet[0].notes[0]`. Also, beware that you are setting a global variable (perhaps on a browser's window object) when you type `dataSet = ...` What you probably want is to declare a variable local to the function with `var dataSet = ...`